# ms-access tricky situation in product entry

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have two Access tables access one is were I make entries for products like

```
whitepapter | pen | startDate | endDate
5           | 10  | 31/jan    | 02/feb
```

Stock product table:

```
whitepapter | pen
10          | 20
```

My goals is: When a user enters data, the application will check against stock product and date:
If the end date is 1st january it show those 5 papers and 10 pens minus main stock, but if today is 03 february it will put them back to main stock:

What is the best way to approach this? I know about relation but i'm asking how to apply this in best way... The users that use this DB are not professionals so I'm looking the best way to give them this feature....

Comment: Should you have it automatically put things back in stock?

Comment: I do not understand what start and end date are. Start and end of what? Can you please explain!

Comment: Start date or end date of event...yeah I want this automatic ... the product table is base...that is the maximum number of product available so release product with start product release date and end date of release...so what it should do it will check today date minus end date +1 then it will show the product stock in... if it's not today then it will show the number of product out of stock...thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the number of products needed now with this SELECT query:

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(whitepaper) AS SumOfWihtepapers,
    SUM(pen) AS SumOfPens
FROM
    EventTable
WHERE
    Now Between startDate AND endDate;
```

Also in Access you can use the `AfterUpdate` events of the TextBoxes in order to perform some logic.

---

As for the rest: At StackOverflow we like to help you when you got stuck while trying to programm something, but you must show some effort. What have you tried? Can you show us some code? Did it not work like expected? Did you get an error message?

Please read the section **Get answers to practical, detailed questions** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)